# Toggle camera from back to front while continuing recording with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I have created an iOS app where I can take videos and photos and save them to my gallery on my iPhone. My problem is that I want to keep recording while taking a video before saving. It is an option recently added to WhatsApp or other apps, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
-(BOOL)toggleCamera
{
    BOOL success=NO;

    if (self.cameraCount>1)
    {
        NSError* error;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput* newVedioInput;
        AVCaptureDevicePosition position=[self.videoInput.device position];

        if (position==AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
        {
            newVedioInput=[[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:self.frontFacingCamera error:&error];
        }
        else if (position==AVCaptureDevicePositionFront)
        {
            newVedioInput=[[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:self.backFacingCamera error:&error];
        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }

        if (newVedioInput!=nil)
        {
            [self.session beginConfiguration];
            [self.session removeInput:self.videoInput];
            if ([self.session canAddInput:newVedioInput])
            {
                [self.session addInput:newVedioInput];
                self.videoInput=newVedioInput;
            }
            else
            {
                [self.session addInput:self.videoInput];
            }
            [self.session commitConfiguration];
            success=YES;
        }
        else if (error)
        {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(recordManager:didFailWithError:)])
            {
                [self.delegate recordManager:self didFailWithError:error];
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

When I do this, the session changes and the video is saved before flipping the camera and that is not what I need. Can anyone help?

Comment: I haven't worked with AVFoundation much, but a solution for you might be to save the recording of your first video (i.e. the front camera), then save the recording of your second video (i.e. the back camera), and then create an AVComposition of both of these videos, combining them together. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcomposition

Comment: this might be a good idea even though i haven't worked with AVComposition before, if you have any more tips it would be great, if not well i'll do some research, thanks!

Comment: From my understanding, a composition is made from several media types, called AVCompositionTracks, which can be composed of AVAssetTracks and AVAudioTracks. 
You would essentially create a new composition and specify The AVCompositionTracks you want to insert into the composition, along with the time they start and end at (directly determining the duration of each track). You can get these start and end times essentially from the duration of the recordings you've made. Some added research would definitely help though!

Comment: i was thinking, is there a way to keep writing to the same outputfile even if i change cameras from front to back?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if that works. I think you will end up with making a composition to do that. Check this link out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540195/merging-videos-together-avfoundation/21675309

Comment: i think this is done using this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499781/ios-8-film-from-both-back-and-front-camera check it out hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the output file.

You need to reconfigure the `AVCaptureDeviceInput` input of the `AVCaptureSession` by enclosing the configuration code in `beginConfiguration()` and `commitConfiguration()` method.

> Dispatch the below work to session's private queue using it's sync
> method. eg: sessionQueue.sync{}

```swift
self.session.beginConfiguration()
if let videoInput = self.videoInput {
    self.session.removeInput(videoInput)
}
addVideoInput() //adding `AVCaptureDeviceInput` again
configureSessionQuality() //Configuring session preset here.

// Fix initial frame having incorrect orientation
let connection = self.videoOutput?.connection(with: .video)
if connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported == true {
    connection?.videoOrientation = self.orientation
}

//Fix preview mirroring
if self.cameraLocation == .front {
    if connection?.isVideoMirroringSupported == true {
         connection?.isVideoMirrored = true
    }
}

self.session.commitConfiguration()

//Change zoom scale if needed.
do {
    try self.captureDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
    self.captureDevice?.videoZoomFactor = zoomScale
    self.captureDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> I am using the above approach in my production code. It is working
> perfectly fine